# Iterator to class LoopInfoBase<BasicBlock, Loop>?

Tags: c++, llvm

I read the llvm page on [`LoopInfoBase(BlockT, LoopT)`](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1LoopInfoBase.html#a7a7c8e0e4f836c13c015b62e18f386bd), and understand that it contains information of all top level loops. It also has iterators (and reverse iterators etc) defined within the class template.

I don't quite understand what the iterator is iterating over? For example in `vector<int>`, an iterator `i` would iterate over the container vector and `*i` is an int, in `Map<string, int>`, an iterator `i` would iterate over the map and `*i` would be a pair of type `<string, int>`. However here, there is a class template, so suppose `i` is an iterator of such a class, then what would `*i` represent (alternatively what would be it's type)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case of the file you mention the type of iterator is

```
typedef std::vector<LoopT *>::const_iterator llvm::LoopInfoBase< BlockT, LoopT >::iterator
```

So we see it is const_iterator (an iterator of const values) of a vector of LoopT pointers.

Im a little curious on why you are diving into the LLVM docs. If you are attempting to learn C++ I would not reccomend trying to learn through the LLVM compiler docs, seems like a overly difficult way to learn the language. Try tutorials like http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/